# deadkeys show "Emacs-Lisp:" when in Emacs-List-mode

Tags: emacs, keyboard

I have a problem with my emacs config...
When trying to insert dead chars like ', ~ and " when in emacs-lisp-mode, the only thing that happens is the minibuffer that show "Emacs-Lisp:" and my char isn't inserted.

Note that it doesn't happend when in C/C++ mode :/

My keyboard config is "us_intl" with dead keys.
Emacs version: 24.3.1

My config:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/61880d721172c0cf0db1

Comment: Have you tried recursively bisecting your config file? Does the same behaviour occur when you don't use a config file?